# Is there a way that i can translate Python regular expression to JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, python, regex

I have been having trouble trying to translate python regular expression to a JavaScript regular expression here is the python code `r/^([ab].*\1$ | ^[ab]$/` and this was my JavaScript translation `/([^ab]*.\1$) | [^ab]$/gm` I have to make it match 'a', 'aa', 'bababbb' and it is not supposed to match 'ab', 'baba'. Thank you so much for your help!

For better Clarification:

I did test my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUbyY.png), and I was still getting false and false when I was supposed to get true and false

Here is a picture of the question
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfur8.jpg)

Here is the solution they gave in python for this question [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGiOZ.jpg)

I hope that was able to clear up some confusion :) Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: I don't get it.  What's the rule you're trying to encode?

Comment: It would be beneficial to see test cases and expected outputs in order to help. (The first example isn't even valid regex; there's no closing parentheses.)

Comment: I can see at least 4 differences between the Python solution in the picture and the one in the question. Your JavaScript solution has even more differences. Maybe try to copy it correctly and then see if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern `r/^([ab].*\1$ | ^[ab]$/` does not seems to be a valid Python regex notation.

The question is to match a string made up of the characters a and b, and match strings that begin with the same letter.

For that scenario, you can use:

```
^([ab])(?:[ab]*\1)?$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `([ab])` Capture **group 1**, match either a or b
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `[ab]*\1` Optionally match a or b followed by a backreference `\1` to match the same character as in group 1.
- `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional to also just allow a single character in total
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/91ElQR/1)

```js
const regex = /^([ab])(?:[ab]*\1)?$/;
[
  "a",
  "aa",
  "bababbb",
  "ab",
  "baba",
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} --> ${regex.test(s)}`))
```